# How do I apply a class to the entire form generated by simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Per [the docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) I have tried many variations, but none seem to work.

What I would like to happen is this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings" class="simple_form new_listing form-horizontal" id="new_listing" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

But when I tried this:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @listing, :defaults => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

This is generated:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings" class="simple_form new_listing" id="new_listing" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Notice no `form-horizontal` in the class attribute.

When I try:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @listing, :defaults => { :wrapper_html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } } do |f| %>
```

This is the output generated:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings" class="simple_form new_listing" id="new_listing" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

It also applies that class to all the elements within the form, e.g.:

```
<div class="control-group select optional form-horizontal">
```

Which is not the outcome I want.

I also tried this:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @listing, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } } do |f| %>
```

This is the `form` output it produced:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings" class="simple_form new_listing" id="new_listing" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Which looks just like some of the other outputs, but the difference is that it applied that class to all `input` elements within the form, like this:

```
<input class="numeric float optional form-horizontal">
```

So....I have tried everything I can think of, and everything seen in the docs (I think).

What have I missed?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

I also tried the obvious, 'normal' version:

```
<%= simple_form_for @listing, :class => 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
```

That generates this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/listings" class="simple_form new_listing" id="new_listing" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for @listing, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

That doesn't work?